# How to connect Oracle DB with phalcon 3.0

Tags: oracle11g, database-connection, phalcon

I have a project with Phalcon 2.0 and Oracle 11g database and running successfully. I tried to upgrade to Phalcon 3.0 but it is not working.

Comment: You could try to add the [Oracle component form the incubator](https://github.com/phalcon/incubator/blob/master/Library/Phalcon/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Oracle.php). But in the long run, you should consider switch database engine when running with Phalcon.

Answer (score 2):

As of Phalcon version 3.0 Oracle support has been dropped from the project. Quoting from the 3.0 Blog announcement:

> Dropped support of Oracle [#12008](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/pull/12008), [#12009](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/pull/12009) Support of Oracle has been
>   dropped from the Phalcon Core for the following reasons:
>
> - The lack of Oracle maintainer
> - The lack of relevant experience among the Phalcon Core Team
> - Weak support or interest from the community
> - Incomplete implementation that creates only the illusion of support
>     for Oracle
> - Some issues hampering for the support of PHP 7 in Phalcon
>
> [Oracle components will be ported to the Phalcon Incubator](https://github.com/phalcon/incubator/blob/master/Library/Phalcon/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Oracle.php). If the
>   adapter receives support and enhancements from the community, we will
>   consider making it part of the core again.

More info and patch notes in the blog: https://blog.phalconphp.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think they already dropped support with OracleDB in 3.0.x, check it here https://blog.phalconphp.com/post/phalcon-3-0-0-released